# Kafka Streams Application out of memory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We built a Kafka-Streams Application with a rather complex topology:

```
Sub-topology: 0
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [sourceTopic1])
          --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000011, KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000002
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000011 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000012
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000012 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000015
          <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000011
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000015 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000014
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000012
        Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000002 (stores: [])
          --> none
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000014 (topic: pop-to-pop-metrics-store-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000015

      Sub-topology: 1
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001 (topics: [sourceTopic2])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000003
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000003 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005, KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000004
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000006
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000003
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000006 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000009
          <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000009 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000008
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000006
        Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000004 (stores: [])
          --> none
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000003
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000008 (topic: pop-to-site-metrics-store-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000009

      Sub-topology: 2
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000010 (topics: [pop-to-site-metrics-store-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000007
        Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000007 (stores: [pop-to-site-metrics-store])
          --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000017
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000010
        Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000017 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000018
          <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000007
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000018 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000022, KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000033
          <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000017
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000033 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000035
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000018
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000022 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000021
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000018
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000035 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000034
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000033
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000021 (topic: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000018-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000022
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000034 (topic: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000033-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000035

      Sub-topology: 3
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000016 (topics: [pop-to-pop-metrics-store-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000013
        Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000013 (stores: [pop-to-pop-metrics-store])
          --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000019
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000016
        Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000019 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000020
          <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000013
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000020 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000025
          <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000019
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000025 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000024
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000020
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000024 (topic: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000020-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000025

      Sub-topology: 4
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000023 (topics: [KSTREAM-MAP-0000000018-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000027
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000026 (topics: [KSTREAM-MAP-0000000020-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000028
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000027 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000029-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000029
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000023
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000028 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000030-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000030
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000026
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000030 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000029-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000031
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000028
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000029 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000030-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000031
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000027
        Processor: KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000031 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000032
          <-- KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000029, KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000030
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000032 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000038
          <-- KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000031
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000038 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000037
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000032
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000037 (topic: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000032-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000038

      Sub-topology: 5
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000036 (topics: [KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000033-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000040
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000039 (topics: [KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000032-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000041
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000040 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000042-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000042
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000036
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000041 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000043-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000043
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000039
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000043 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000042-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000044
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000041
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000042 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000043-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000044
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000040
        Processor: KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000044 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000045
          <-- KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000042, KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000043
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000045 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000046
          <-- KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000044
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000046 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000047
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000045
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000047 (topic: targetTopic1)
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000046

      Sub-topology: 6
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000048 (topics: [targetTopic1])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000060
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000060 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000062
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000048
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000062 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000061
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000060
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000061 (topic: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000060-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000062

      Sub-topology: 7
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000049 (topics: [sourceTopic3])
          --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000051, KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000050
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000051 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000052
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000049
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000052 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000053
          <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000051
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000053 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000056
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000052
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000056 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000055
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000053
        Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000050 (stores: [])
          --> none
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000049
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000055 (topic: effective-link-selector-store-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000056

      Sub-topology: 8
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000057 (topics: [effective-link-selector-store-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000054
        Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000054 (stores: [effective-link-selector-store])
          --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000058
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000057
        Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000058 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000059
          <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000054
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000059 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000065, KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000073
          <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000058
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000073 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000078
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000059
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000065 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000064
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000059
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000078 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000077
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000073
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000064 (topic: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000059-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000065
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000077 (topic: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000073-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000078

      Sub-topology: 9
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000063 (topics: [KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000060-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000067
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000066 (topics: [KSTREAM-MAP-0000000059-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000068
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000067 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000069-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000069
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000063
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000068 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000070-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000070
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000066
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000070 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000069-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000071
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000068
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000069 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000070-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000071
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000067
        Processor: KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000071 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000072
          <-- KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000069, KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000070
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000072 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000075
          <-- KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000071
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000075 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000074
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000072
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000074 (topic: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000072-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000075

      Sub-topology: 10
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000076 (topics: [KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000072-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000080
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000079 (topics: [KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000073-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000081
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000080 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000082-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000082
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000076
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000081 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000083-store])
          --> KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000083
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000079
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000083 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000082-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000084
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000081
        Processor: KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000082 (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000083-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000084
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000080
        Processor: KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000084 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000085
          <-- KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000082, KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000083
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000085 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000086
          <-- KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000084
        Processor: KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000086 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000087, KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000088
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000085
        Processor: KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000088 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000089
          <-- KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000086
        Processor: KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000087 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000091
          <-- KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000086
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000089 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000094
          <-- KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000088
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000091 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000090
          <-- KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000087
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000094 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000093
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000089
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000090 (topic: KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000087-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000091
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000093 (topic: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000089-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000094

      Sub-topology: 11
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000092 (topics: [KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000087-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000096
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000095 (topics: [KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000089-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000097
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000096 (stores: [KSTREAM-OUTERTHIS-0000000098-store])
          --> KSTREAM-OUTERTHIS-0000000098
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000092
        Processor: KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000097 (stores: [KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000099-store])
          --> KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000099
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000095
        Processor: KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000099 (stores: [KSTREAM-OUTERTHIS-0000000098-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000100
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000097
        Processor: KSTREAM-OUTERTHIS-0000000098 (stores: [KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000099-store])
          --> KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000100
          <-- KSTREAM-WINDOWED-0000000096
        Processor: KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000100 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000101
          <-- KSTREAM-OUTERTHIS-0000000098, KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000099
        Processor: KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000101 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000102
          <-- KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000100
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000102 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000103
          <-- KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000101
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000103 (topic: linkStatus)
          <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000102

      Sub-topology: 12
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000104 (topics: [linkStatus])
          --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000105
        Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000105 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000108
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000104
        Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000108 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000107
          <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000105
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000107 (topic: my-app-agg-store-repartition)
          <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000108

      Sub-topology: 13
        Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000109 (topics: [my-app-agg-store-repartition])
          --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000106
        Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000106 (stores: [my-app-agg-store])
          --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000110
          <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000109
        Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000110 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000111
          <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000106
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000111 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000112
          <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000110
        Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000112 (stores: [])
          --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000113
          <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000111
        Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000113 (topic: finalTargetTopic)
          <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000112
```

When running the service under load the service was OOM killed.

During the execution of the test we noticed an inflation of threads (over 400). Using gdb we tracked them to RocksDb:

> 427  Thread 0x7f97a4722700 (LWP 18049) "java" 0x00007f97d9f6b9f5 in
>   pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0   426 
>   Thread 0x7f9772fe5700 (LWP 18080)  "**rocksdb:dump_st**" 0x00007f97d9f6bda2
>   in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 
>   425  Thread 0x7f97737e6700 (LWP 18081) "java" 0x00007f97d9f6b9f5 in
>   pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0   424 
>   Thread 0x7f9771fe3700 (LWP 18112) "**rocksdb:dump_st**" 0x00007f97d9f6bda2
>   in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 
>   423  Thread 0x7f97697d2700 (LWP 18228) "java" 0x00007f97d9f6b9f5 in
>   pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0   422 
>   Thread 0x7f9767fcf700 (LWP 18244) "**rocksdb:dump_st**" 0x00007f97d9f6bda2
>   in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 
>   421  Thread 0x7f97687d0700 (LWP 18245) "java" 0x00007f97d9f6b9f5 in
>   pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0   420 
>   Thread 0x7f976cfd9700 (LWP 18276) "**rocksdb:dump_st**" 0x00007f97d9f6bda2
>   in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

When stopping the data input flow to the service, the process high memory consumption stays stabile (it does not drop as expected).

We tried to disable RockDb's block cache  to limit its memory use (as described [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html)), but to no avail.

We are running on a CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).
Our machine has 2 vCPUs and 4 GB memory. 
Our JVM is configured to use 500MB.
Our KStream version is 2.3.1

Any ideas?